# array clustering with unique identifier for file datasets

Tags: sql, arrays, database, apache-spark, analytics

I have a dataset with big int array column in s3 and I want to filter rows efficiently based on array values. I know we can use gin index in sql table but need solution to work on s3 dataset. I am planning to use cluster id for each combinations of elements in array (as their cardinality is not huge. max 2500) and then store it as new column on which later on filter can applied.
Example,

```
Table A
+------+------+-----------+
| Col1 | Col2 |   Col3    |
+------+------+-----------+
|    1 |  101 | [123,234] |
|    2 |  102 | [123]     |
|    3 |  103 | [234,345] |
+------+------+-----------+
```

I am trying to add new column like,

```
Table B (column Col3 will be removed from actual schema)
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| Col1 | Col2 |   Col3    | Cid       |
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |  101 | [123,234] |    1      |
|    2 |  102 | [123]     |    2      |
|    3 |  103 | [234,345] |    3      |
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

and there will be another table of mapping for col3 and Cid like,

```
Table C
+-----------+-----+
|   Col3    | Cid |
+-----------+-----+
| [123,234] |   1 |
| [123]     |   2 |
| [234,345] |   3 |
+-----------+-----+
```

This table C will be added a new entry if a new combination is created and B will be updated if any array element gets added or removed. Goal is to be able to filter out records from Table A based on values in array column efficiently. Queries like
`123 = Any(Col3)` can be served as `Cid = 2` or queries like [123, 345] = Any(Col3) can be served as `Cid in (2,3)`.

Is there any better way to do solve this problem?
Also I am thinking of creating required combinations at runtime to limit number of combinations. Is it a good idea to create minimum combinations?

Comment: Please can you tag your question with the database you are using? Thanks

Comment: Currently storing in array format in postgres but don't want to store it in db. Need this for S3 store with spark.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can create the table and use `join` to calculate the values:

```
create table array_dim as 
    select col3 as arr, row_number() over (order by min(col1)) as array_id
    from t
    group by col3;
```

You can then add the new column:

```
select a.*, ad.array_id
from a join 
     array_dim ad
     on a.col3 = ad.arr
```

Comment: can you update what is 'a' in first query's group by clause? its arr i I believe. Not able to update answer because of min char limit.

Comment: Thanks for answer Gordon. Also additional question was, is this approach correct or any other better solution to handle such situation?